# Fail to upload image

Tags: android, image, file-upload, kotlin

I am trying to upload an image,found this code([reference](https://github.com/hussien89aa/KotlinUdemy/blob/master/Android/TwitterDemo/StartUp/app/src/main/java/com/hussein/startup/Login.kt)).The code in the file is built for `API >=23`,mine is 21.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun checkPermission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){...

 fun SaveImageInFirebase(){
        var currentUser =mAuth!!.currentUser
        val email:String=currentUser!!.email.toString() //line 125
        val storage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        val storgaRef=storage.getReferenceFromUrl("")
        val df= SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss")
        val dataobj= Date()
        val imagePath= SplitString(email) + "."+ df.format(dataobj)+ ".jpg"
        val ImageRef=storgaRef.child("images/"+imagePath )
        imageView.isDrawingCacheEnabled=true
        imageView.buildDrawingCache()
        val drawable=imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable
        val bitmap=drawable.bitmap
        val baos= ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos)
        val data= baos.toByteArray()
        val uploadTask=ImageRef.putBytes(data)
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener{
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"fail to upload",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
            var DownloadURL= taskSnapshot.downloadUrl!!.toString()
            Log.d("Download Url:",DownloadURL)
        } }
```

When I click on the upload button it throws a NPE at

> .register.SaveImageInFirebase(register.kt:125)                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick

Comment: why -1?What's wrong?

Comment: have you opened internet connection,the code looks good to me!